# I need to run a program, as sudo, on boot, in screen... Tried a few things but can't get it all to work

Tags: boot, bash, sudo, screen, services

My goals are:

1. I have "myprogram" that needs to be run in sudo
2. I want to run it as a service at boot
3. I want it to run inside screen so I can monitor it

So I can do 1&2 just fine, but once I try to add screen to it, it fails.

I have my service setup to run at boot, I have "myprogram" in `/usr/local/sbin`, so in the script that I have the service pointed to, I have :

```
#!/usr/bash
/usr/local/sbin/myprogram -options
```

that works, it boots up, runs the program. but I can't go in and check the output and make sure everything is running fine if I want to check it later. So I want to run it in screen, so I tried

```
#!/usr/bash
/usr/bin/screen -S myprogram /usr/local/sbin/myprogram -options
```

but then when I reboot, nothing happens. If I remove `/usr/bin/screen -S myprogram` then it works. and seeing that I am running it at boot, I can't find any errors to fix it.

Comment: try /etc/rc.local , rc-local.service

Comment: "I want it to run inside screen so I can monitor it": could you explain this a bit more please? Why would you need `screen` in order to monitor something? Wouldn't it be simpler to print to a log file and then `tail -f` the log? Or set up a proper systemd service and use `journalctl`?

Comment: I use screen to monitor lots of things... it's such a handy program. I even use the windowing functions sometimes and the 'watch' for changes, running multiple consoles at the same time and whatnot over ssh... I guess you could say I'm kind of a power-user when it comes to working with linux. a "basic" tty is just not enough for me, and using gui's are not really my thing when it comes to servers, but I still like some of that higher functionality you get from things like screen... and I love how if I disconnect, I can just reconnect like nothing ever happened...